# Add character to file name if duplicate when moving with bash

Tags: bash, duplicates, mv

I currently use a bash script and PDFgrep to rename files to a certain structure. However, in order to stop overriding if the new file has a duplicate name, I want to add a number at the end of the name. Keep in mind that there may be 3 or 4 duplicate names. What's the best way to do this?

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
   echo Usage: Renamer file
   exit 1
fi
f="$1"
id1=$(pdfgrep -m 1 -i "MR# :  " "$f" | grep -oE "[M][0-9][0-9]+") || continue
id2=$(pdfgrep -m 1 -i "Visit#" "$f" | grep -oE "[V][0-9][0-9]+") || continue
{ read today; read dob; read dop; } < <(pdfgrep -i " " "$f" | grep -oE "[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]")
dobsi=$(echo $dob | sed -e 's/\//-/g')
dopsi=$(echo $dop | sed -e 's/\//-/g')
mv -- "$f" "${id1}_${id2}_$(printf "$dobsi")_$(printf "$dopsi")_1.pdf"
```

Comment: `$(printf "$dob")` should probably just be `$dob`. I doubt that `$dob` and `$dop` are printf format strings, and if they are you need additional arguments for the formatting operators.

Comment: I actually pasted the wrong code. I updated with the corrected version.

Comment: It's still wrong to use `printf` like that. If you need to use printf, it should be `printf "%s" "$dobsi"`

Comment: If you know your output filename format is always to append `[0-9][0-9]` if the name is a duplicate, you can do `newname=filename; cnt=1; while [ -f "$newname" ]; do printf -v ver "%02d" "$((cnt++)); newname="${filename%.pdf}${ver}.pdf"; done`  Then save as `$newname`. (there are many variations on this scheme)

Comment: `continue` needs a `for`, `while` or `until` loop - I don't see any of those. Instead of escaping slashes in `sed` substitute commands, use an alternate delimiter: `dobsi=$(echo $dob | sed -e 's|/|-|g')`

Answer (score 2):

Use a loop that checks if the destination filename exists, and increments a counter if it does. Replace the `mv` line with this:

```
prefix="${id1}_{id2}_${dob}_${dop}"
counter=0
while true
do
    if [ "$counter" -ne 0 ]
    then target="${prefix}_${counter}.pdf"
    else target="${prefix}.pdf"
    fi
    if [ ! -e "$target" ]
    then
        mv -- "$f" "$target"
        break
    fi
    ((counter++))
done
```

Note that this suffers from a [TOCTTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) problem, if the duplicate file is created between the `! -f "$target"` test and the `mv`. I thought it would be possible to replace the existence check with using `mv -n`; but while this won't overwrite the file, it still treats the `mv` as successful, so you can't test the result to see if you need to increment the counter.